# How to connect to internet through Ubuntu VM

Tags: networking, ubuntu, proxy, openvpn

I don't know if this is simple or possible (if this is solved by openvpn or something).

I have an Ubuntu VM, that is connected to a proxy, so I can access some webpages that I cannot outside the VM.
At my host machine (windows), I cannot install the proxy, so I cannot access the same webpages, but I want to use the ethernet interface from Ubuntu to do so.

Is this possible in anyway?

I'm using Hyper-V, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Windows 10.

Comment: Your question is unclear. specifically, what does "I can access some webpages that I cannot" mean? Where is the proxy? What gas Internet, what doesnt? (Also, are you sure this is an Internet and not a DNS issue? What do traceroutes shiw? What is your IP addressing scheme?)

Comment: If the VM already used a proxy you should be able to get what you want by establishing an ssh port forwarding from a TCP port on your windows OS through the ssh client to the VM that runs the ssh server and the destination of the ssh port farting is the port of the proxy used by the VM. Then on Windows you just have to point a program to use the ssh forwarded port as proxy.

Comment: to try to give more information, what I'm saying is: at my VM, I'm using pulse secure, but I cannot use it on windows, so, after connecting with pulse secure, some pages (from my company) are available that aren't at windows and I'm trying to use just the network adapter from Ubuntu to reach the same pages (the network adapter used at Hyper-V is an external one, so the Ubuntu is reachable at my network, has one ip from my NAT and so on)